# Will AWS cut off my free service if I go over a limit?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, web-services

Ok I've never used AWS but I wanna dive in to dev opts and I thought I'd start with AWS.   My big tasks are learning to deploy a website to an EC2 and learn Route 58 for URLs.  Next I want to try to make a Continuous Integration with Jenkins.  I'm really nervous that I'm going to get charged which is making me nervous to even try these things.

**QUESTION:**
Will AWS cut me off when/if I go over my trial?  I really dont know what to expect when they say free.  I'd rather AWS turn off before it starts charging me.  How can i do this if it's not standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they won't. You are required to provide your billing information beforehand - if you stick to the [free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) then you will not be charged.

But if you exceed the limits they put in place, you're simply charged for what you use. There's enough Linux and Windows instance hours to run a single micro instance across a month, but if you were to run two of those instances or run a medium-sized one you would be charged for it. If you ran 1000 micro instance hours, you'd be charged for (1000-750 = 250) hours of micro instances. If you ran the medium, you'd be charged the whole lot, because that's not covered under the tier.

Whether you want to stay under it each month or not is up to you.

But they won't stop giving you the free tier until a year expires.

Comment: The documentation also includes step by step instructions on creating an alert that will notify you if you exceed the free tier allowed usage: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/create-billing-alarm.html